# Is my AMD hybrid-graphics card supported by Ubuntu 16.04 driver?

Tags: drivers, radeon, 16.04, lts, hybrid-graphics

so before I try a clean install of 16.04 LTS when it's released, is there any way to find out whether my AMD graphics card is fully supported by the driver?

I'm not talking gaming, just the open source driver that is replacing the fglrx driver. I'm using a hybrid Intel/AMD system.

Here's my card:

```
04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] (rev ff)`
```

Comment: You can boot off the installer and just "try ubuntu" and see how well the drivers work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 16.04 the AMD graphics card driver is AMDGPU. The list of supported cards is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) . This says your card is fully supported.

Comment: Just a quick comment - a clean install worked like a charm - the AMD GPU driver is better than the catalyst in 14.04! At least for this hybrid! ha!

Comment: I have Toshiba Satellite L850 laptop that runs Windows and it has AMD Radeon 7600M graphic. I could not see it in the resources page that you've regarded. Is there any way to test my graphics compatibility through live CD before the installation of Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Yes. Run Ubuntu 16.04 from a live DVD. It should load AMDGPU and if it works you are good.  I think the 7600M is a TURKS implementation so it should probably be fully supported.

Comment: i don't really understand the list. my device output: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760] (rev ff). how do i know if mine is supported?

Comment: @MycrofD Please ask a new question. Include the results of sudo lshw -C video

Comment: Isnt it the case that in addition to `AMDGPU` theres still good old `radeon` open-source drivers? So that list would only be showing some of the open-source GPU-s supported.