# Is my AMD radeon graphics card supported by Ubuntu 16.04 driver?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

[Similar Q at [Is my AMD hybrid-graphics card supported by Ubuntu 16.04 driver?](https://askubuntu.com/q/759664/329036) . However, I was asked to put a new question for my specifics.]

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I use AMD Radeon graphics. Is it compatible?
Here are the results of `sudo lshw -C video`:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Results for `glxinfo | grep rendering`:

```
direct rendering: Yes
```

Results for `lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff)
```

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, your GPUs should work "out of the box" under Ubuntu 16.04, which should automatically be using the `radeon` driver for the HD 6400M. Unfortunately, since the HD 6400M predates the GCN architecture, you will be unable to use the newer and faster `amdgpu` driver.

To switch to the dGPU, you can follow the instructions on the Arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME#PRIME_GPU_offloading

So you would put something like the following in your `.xprofile`:

```
xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink radeon Intel
```

and then to run something with the dGPU, you would prepend the command with `DRI_PRIME=1`. For example:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears
```

(I believe it's possible to create a `.desktop` file that does this for specific applications, if you prefer a more graphical interface)